# Get all the true values of dataframe from a pandas dictonary based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. Trying to implement below condition but getting below error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.any() or a.all().
```

Below is my code:

```
   df['col2'].fillna('.', inplace=True)
   import copy
   dict_YM = {}
   for yearmonth in [201104, 201105,  201106,201107,201108,201109,201110,201111,201112,
              201201,201202,201203,201204, 201205, 201206,201207,201208,201209,201210,201211,201212,
              201301,201302,201303,201304, 201305, 201306,201307,201308,201309,201310,201311,201312,
              201401,201402,201403,201404, 201405, 201406,201407,201408,201409,201410,201411,201412,
              201501,201502,201503,201504, 201505, 201506,201507,201508,201509,201510,201511,201512,
              201601,201602,201603,201604,201605]:

       key_name = 'text'+str(yearmonth)
       c1=df['col1']
       c2=df['col2']
       c3=df['flag']


      if((yearmonth >= c1) & (yearmonth < c2) & (c3==1)):
          print "in if ..."
          dict_YM [key_name] = copy.deepcopy(df)
          dict_YM [key_name].loc[:, 'col4'] = yearmonth
      elif((yearmonth >= c1) & (c2==".") & (c3==1)):
          print "in else if"
          dict_YM [key_name] = copy.deepcopy(df)
          dict_YM [key_name].loc[:, 'col4'] = yearmonth

  dict_YM
```

Now i understand we need to use c1.all() or c1.any(). But my requirement is for all the only true values of yearmonth >= c1 and yearmonth < c2 and c3==1 want do some operation. But if i use all then few of rows has true records and if go by any then the false record are also getting. Please help me how i can solve obove condition as each value/row check not as a series.

Note: col1 is int and col2,flag are float as they contain nan as well.

Edit: I am not trying to compare the string(yearmonth) is greater with whole df column (col1) but actually i want to iterate over the column col1 of df if condition satisfies then respective operation should perform those rows only.

```
 Also df has huge records with various columns but col1 and col2 will have data as we have yearmonth in dictonary and flag will have 1 or nan.

 Col2 has data like this {192106.0,192107.0, 195103.0 etc}  and col1 has data like this {192104,201204,201206 etc}
```

Please let me know if you need any other inputs.

EDIT2: df col1, col2, flag sample data values

```
  df

  col1       col2           flag
  192104     NaN            1.0
  192104     200301.0       1.0
  200301     201204.0       1.0
  201204     NaN            0.0
  200410     201206.0       1.0
  201206     NaN            0.0
  192104     198001.0       1.0
  198001     NaN            1.0
```

Edit 3: I have tried like this but getting is not working seems did any one get any idea i am stuck with this issue:

```
 dict_YM [key_name] =np.where(
    (df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & 
                                (df['col2']>yearmonth) & (df['Active']==1)]),
    copy.deepcopy(df),
    np.where((df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & 
                                         (df['col2']==".") & (df['Active']==1)]),
             copy.deepcopy(df),np.nan))
then i can add col4 once dict_YM [key_name] got generated
```

Got below error when i tried above code:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (8,3) ()
```

Comment: You probably need to show what df looks like. The problem stems from you are asking if string (yearmonth) is bigger than a whole column of data (c1), which does not make any sense.

Comment: not whole column but each row of data(c1) kind of iteration over the column c1

Comment: i have edit the question please let me know if you understand my requirement correctly ?

Comment: Can you correct the indentation in the question and provide a minimal example of `df`?

Comment: @MaartenFabré i have edited the question as per you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your edit 3. For the np.where function with signature `np.where: (condition, [x, y])`, the shape of `condition, x, and y` must be the same.

Focusing on what you are passing in np.where

```
np.where(
    (df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & (df['col2']>yearmonth) & (df['Active']==1)]),
    copy.deepcopy(df),
    np.where(
        (df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & (df['col2']==".") & (df['Active']==1)]),
        copy.deepcopy(df),
        np.nan
    )
)
```

The error is generated by the third argument you pass into the external np.where function. You pass in an argument with no shape (`np.nan`).

If you want to apply a function only to rows where certain conditions are satisfied, one approach (not necessarily the best) is to store the indices and use a map function over the rows. Like so.

```
col1 = np.array([ 192104, 192104, 200301, 201204, 200410, 201206, 192104, 198001])
flag = np.array([ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0])
col2 = np.array([ np.nan, 200301, 201204, np.nan, 201206, np.nan, 198001, np.nan])

col_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'flag']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([col1, col2, flag]).T, columns=col_names)
inds_to_transform = df.query("col1 <= {0} & col2 > {0} & flag == 1".format(200608)).index
df.loc[inds_to_transform] = df.loc[inds_to_transform].applymap(lambda x : x+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for my own question posting it as it may be helpful for others:

```
 df['col2'].fillna('.', inplace=True)
 import copy
 dict_YM = {}
 e={}
 f={}
 for yearmonth in [201104, 201105,  201106,201107,201108,201109,201110,201111,201112,
          201201,201202,201203,201204, 201205, 201206,201207,201208,201209,201210,201211,201212,
          201301,201302,201303,201304, 201305, 201306,201307,201308,201309,201310,201311,201312,
          201401,201402,201403,201404, 201405, 201406,201407,201408,201409,201410,201411,201412,
          201501,201502,201503,201504, 201505, 201506,201507,201508,201509,201510,201511,201512,
          201601,201602,201603,201604,201605]:

   key_name = 'text'+str(yearmonth)
   c1=df['col1']
   c2=df['col2']
   c3=df['flag']


  e[key_name]=df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & (df['col2']>yearmonth) 
                              & (df['flag']==1)]

f[key_name]=df[(df['col1']<=yearmonth) & (df['col2']==".")
                             & (df['Active']==1)]

if not e[key_name].empty:
    dict_YM [key_name] =e[key_name]
    dict_YM [key_name].loc[:, 'col4'] = yearmonth
elif not f[key_name].empty:
    dict_YM [key_name] =f[key_name]
    dict_YM [key_name].loc[:, 'col4'] = yearmonth

dict_YM
```